# Second question regarding dw in assembly and nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I wrote this in my program `Second: dw "ABCD"` It would make send to me using little endian that the resulting by sequence in memory would like this 0x42, 0x41, 0x44, 0x43, but instead it printed this 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44. Can you use any define directive i.e. db, dw, dd to assign a string, and why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is just a sequence of individual bytes, and has no endianness.

If you want it treated as a number, you have to define it as a number, 0x42414443 or whatever order you need.